# Dynamically updating form with Django

Tags: javascript, django

I need to build a web form with a number of select fields whose choices depend on the answers to the previous fields.  A classic example of this would be a vehicle year > make > model form, where the select choices for make do not populate until a year is chosen and the select choices for model do not populate until a make is chosen.  The sql to populate each individual field would look something like this:

```
select distinct year from cars

select distinct make from cars where year = [answer above]

select distinct model from cars where year = [answer above] and make = [answer above]
```

It will be a part of a project that is already implemented in Django, so I'd like this to be implemented with Django as well.  Although I have no experience with this type of form, I do have a rudimentary understanding of the asynchronous javascript calls that must happen to support it.

Form looks like this:

```
class CarForm(forms.Form):
    year = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_years())
    make = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_makes(year))
    model = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_models(year, make))
```

View looks like this:

```
def save_car(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CarForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_results(form.cleaned_data)
            return HttpResponse('Success')
    else:
        form = CarForm()
    return render_to_response('car.html', locals())
```

My biggest question is just how to update the choices for each of the select fields.  Any help with that would be great!

Comment: are you using jquery in your application ?

Comment: Yes, jQuery is already being used for several other things in the application.

Comment: then, when selected index changes, call a view via ajax which modifies the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

I recommend taking a look at this post [on ajax with jquery in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369667/django-ajax-jquery-call)

When you get the call back in your view for this ajax call you can check what context is being passed in the request. Based upon that data you can filter down the results of your dropdown.

It looks like you already have some methods or functions that get you the specific details your looking for. You can pass the data from request directly into these.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by overriding the django forms **_*init*_** method and javascript in templates.
Check [Here](http://sunnyarorablog.wordpress.com/2014/04/07/create-dynamic-forms-using-django-and-javascript/)