# django request.POST.get different button name

Tags: django, request

HELLO，I have many buttons like:

```
<button name="A"></button>
<button name="B"></button>
<button name="C"></button>
```

When I click on a button, I want to get the corresponds name, then use it in my view to compare with some string.
 request.POST.get how to get the value I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use `request.POST.get` you need to have the buttons wrapped in an HTML `<form></form>` and get the data using [django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/)

Comment: yeah,thanks, but I want to know how to get the corresponds name when I click on one button, I forgot one thing to show, my buttons’ name are dynamically generated.So I don't know how to get it

Comment: you want to know what button was clicked?

Comment: that should be a client side logic - you should get that information in javascript, before `post`-ing, and then `post` with that information, as an additional key-value pair of information

Comment: Thanks，but I hardly ever learned JS，can you show me a example please？

Comment: [This is how you get the name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398534/javascript-get-the-name-of-a-clicked-button) and then you need to perform an ajax request. There are plenty of examples on how to do that with Django, [I'll give you one such example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369667/django-ajax-jquery-call)