# django get data from api with ajax

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

I was trying to get some information from **API using ajax**. I was able to post data but **I was unable to get all the data from the server**. I am new in the Django environment, though i have tried some references. **I was wanted to get the data from the server using the API that I provide and show those data by using ajax get call.**

**References that I have followed:**

1.[Django Ajax Jquery Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369667/django-ajax-jquery-call)

2.https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/15/how-to-implement-a-crud-using-ajax-and-json.html

3.https://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/python/11762/python-django-simple-crud-ajax.html

**My code for get call:**

```
         $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/save_composition",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data)
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus) {
                   alert("error..");
            }});
```

**Url section :**

```
path('restore_composition/', views.restore_composition, name='restore_composition')
```

**Views.py:**

```
def restore_composition(request):
   data = SaveComposition.objects.all()
   return render(request, 'index.html', context={'data': data})
```

Comment: Where have you defined your `save_composition` `method/url` ?

Comment: I misunderstood at some point. The endpoint was the issue.Thanks for your co-operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how ajax calls works in Django framework.

```
def ajax_method():
    return HttpResponse(200)
```

**url to the ajax call**

```
path('save_composition', views.ajax_method, name='ajax_method')
```

You need to set the `url-path' without forward-slash

**Ajax call**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "save_composition",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data)
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus) {
               alert("error..");
        }});
```

Comment: Ok, it seems the right way and I already mentioned that I am new in Django and ajax environment, so thanks for your co-operation.