# Populating Table Based on Drop Down Selection

Tags: django, for-loop, drop-down-menu

Hi I'm trying to create a table that will show values based on the selected name. For instance if a drop down existed and a value was chosen, the rest of the fields would show the data associated with that chosen value.

```
<div class="main-items">
    <h2>Database</h2>
        <div class="card-items">

            <table class="main-items-table">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="menu-box-tab-items-identifiers">Name:</td>

                            {% for d in database %}
                            <td class="menu-box-tab-items" href="/cusip/{{d.company_name}}"><span>{{d.name}}</span></td>
                            {% endfor %}

                        </tr>



                        <tr>
                            <td class="menu-box-tab-items-identifiers">Item:</td>

                            {% for d in database %}
                            <td class="menu-box-tab-items"><span>{{d.item}}</span></td>
                            {% endfor %}

                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td class="menu-box-tab-items-identifiers">Method of Shipment:</td>

                            {% for d in database %}
                            <td class="menu-box-tab-items" href="#6"><span>{{d.method_of_shipment}}</span></td>
                            {% endfor %}

                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td class="menu-box-tab-items-identifiers">Days:</td>

                            {% for d in database %}
                            <td class="menu-box-tab-items" href="#6"><span>{{d.days}}</span></td>
                            {% endfor %}

                        </tr>

                     
                        <tr>
                            <td class="menu-box-tab-items-identifiers">Location:</td>
                            {% for d in database %}
                                <td class="menu-box-tab-items"><a href="https://www.google.com/search?q={{d.location}}"></span>{{d.location}}</a></td>
                            {% endfor %}

                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td class="menu-box-tab-items-identifiers">Country:</td>
                            {% for d in database %}
                            <td class="menu-box-tab-items" href="#6"><span>{{d.country}}</span></td>
                            {% endfor %}

                        </tr>


                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
</div>
```

Basically, if a drop down menu existed for all the "names", I would want all the other td's to show the data associated with that name. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are:

1. To require the user to submit the form once the first option has been selected and to then refresh the template with related options in the other fields. You would need some code in your `forms.py` file that can take the provided option and filter the other querysets accordingly.
2. Use javascript and an AJAX request to dynamically update the other field options once the first field has been selected, here is some useful information:

[Django Ajax Jquery Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369667/django-ajax-jquery-call)

Comment: Hey, thank you for this, I think I figured it out. I basically put a request.Get.get("...") in my views.py file to filter through the dropdown and it seems to be working. I had one more question that arised now that I figured this part out, I bascially made the page refresh each time a new filter is chosen, which reverts the chosen selection back to the first one, even though the data is populated correctly. I was wondering if you knew a way to keep the chosen selection as the visible choice in the dropdown menu, even though the page got refreshed again. Thanks again.

Comment: If you want to keep it into the next view then pass `request.GET.get("...")` into your context as a variable and you can access it in your template to keep the select option